# Convexity of a perspective of affine function

Tags: convex-analysis

I was reading the well-known convex optimization PDF lesson by Boyd and Vandenberghe (more specifically [chapter 3](http://stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/functions.pdf)), and ran into a problem which I haven't been to solve.

On slide 3-20, the perspective function of a function *f* is defined as :
$$g(x,t) = t f({x \over t})$$ assuming $$f : {\rm I\!R}^n → {\rm I\!R}$$ so that $$g : {\rm I\!R}^{n+1} → {\rm I\!R}$$ and also $${x \over t} \in dom f, t > 0$$

The slide says the perspective *g* of the function *f* is convex is *f* is itself convex, before naming 3 examples of functions of which convexity can be proven using this theorem.
The first 2 examples seem rather straightforward to me ; however the 3<sup>rd</sup> example : $$g(x) = (c^T x + d) f ({{Ax + b} \over {c^T x + d}})$$ surprised me a bit ; the slide says this function is convex if *f* is convex.

It appears the $$g(x,t) = t f({x \over t})$$ function is used here : $$g(Ax + b, c^T x + d) = (c^T x + d) f ({{Ax + b} \over {c^T x + d}})$$
However, I don't quite understand why composing the *g* function with the function mapping *x* to *Ax + b*, and restricting the *t* variable to have $$t = c^T x + d$$ wouldn't break the *g* function's convexity ; isn't such function composition subject to the function composition rules defined in slide 3-18 (*Vector Composition*) ?

Any idea about what I'm missing here ?
Thanks in advance for your valuable help guys !

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured out the answer by myself… from what I understood, the reasoning here consists in using a very simple theorem mentioned in slide 3-14 :

> *f (Ax + b)* is convex if *f* is convex

noting that *g(x,t)* can be expressed as *g(x<sub>a</sub>)* where x<sub>a</sub> is an "augmented vector variable" :

$$x_a = (x,t) = (x_1, …, x_n, t)$$

and also that :

$$(Ax + b, c^T x + d) = \left( \begin{array}{}A & 0 \\ c^T & 0 \\ \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{}x \\ t \\ \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{}b \\ d \\ \end{array} \right) = A_a \cdot x_a + b_a $$

with :
$$A_a = \left( \begin{array}{}A & 0 \\ c^T & 0 \\ \end{array} \right), b_a = \left( \begin{array}{}b \\ d \\ \end{array} \right)$$

so we have :
$$g (Ax + b, c^T x + d) = g(A_a x_a + b_a)$$

We know that *f(x)* is convex so *g (x<sub>a</sub>) = g (x, t)* is convex too (see theorem about the perspective of functions in my original post), and using the theorem mentioned above in this post, we can deduce that g (A<sub>a</sub> x<sub>a</sub> + b<sub>a</sub>) is convex as well, hence :

$$h(x) = (c^T x + d) f ({{Ax + b} \over {c^T x + d}})$$ is convex if *f* is convex.